# internally schedule an update in iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, scheduled-tasks

When the application which we built is offline or closed, Is it possible to pop up a message to open an application without the influence of back-end server ? Say for every one week ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in 3.0.  Starting in iOS 4 you can use local notifications that don't require a server which is explained better [on this blog](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/07/31/adding-local-notifications-with-ios-4.html).

Answer (score 2):

No. It isn't possible without server interaction (Push Notification).